# internet connection sharing assigned IP

Tags: macos, internet, internet-sharing

Setting the internet connection sharing is straighforward from the `OSX` preferences. So I set the sharing via the ethernet cable so that when I `ifconfig`, I see some new entry `bridge100` that is has `192.168.2.1` `IP` . 
Then I connected my `pi` via the ethernet. Now, I try to find the `IP` that is assigned to the `PI` but when I ping the subnet `192.168.2.*`, I get nothing else but `192.168.2.1`. However, I notice that the ethernet cable is using `en5` interface but with no `IP`. Do I need to set a static `IP` to `en5` ?

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a4:5e:60:d9:e4:51 
    inet6 fe80::a65e:60ff:fed9:e451%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.43.14 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:00:1f:0c:50 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:00:1f:0c:51 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether a6:5e:60:9d:1f:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:5e:60:d9:e4:51 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
    ether d6:8c:e1:bd:55:69 
    inet6 fe80::d48c:e1ff:febd:5569%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en5: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=4<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 20:c9:d0:2a:ee:68 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether a6:5e:60:9d:1f:64 
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::a45e:60ff:fe9d:1f64%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en5 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: Please add the output of ifconfig. If it is the same as here: [assigning static IP with command line](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205633/assigning-static-ip-with-command-line) better rework both questions. Your interfaces are a mess. You have four ethernet interfaces, a vlan and a bridge and we don't know what you really want to accomplish. The best thing to do is to add a map of your network environment and your superior goal.

Comment: @klanomath I have just edited my post. What I want to do is `ssh` into my `PI`. So I cabled it via `ethernet` to my mac, after activating the internet sharing

Comment: Does the vlan (en5) have any purpose?

Comment: @klanomath en5 appears when I plugg the ethernet cable

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to display Internet-to-Ethernet address using the arp utility ? `arp -a` will display the connected devices to your network via ethernet.

It will show something like this :
`(192.168.100.104) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on en0 ifscope [ethernet]`